# what's the proper way to implement darkmode in VueJs with SASS using variables

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, darkmode

What is the best implementation for dark-mode toggle feature if I am using sass with VueJS
i have a project with sass variables for the colors.

```
/* variables */
/* ------------- */
$bg-main: #f8f8f8;
$btn-secondary-c: #f6f6f6;
$bg-items: #fff;
$text-c-1: #625f6e;
$text-c-2: #5e5873;
$color-main: #6e6b7b;
$shadow-c: rgba(34, 41, 47, 0.05);
/* ------- */
```

and it has its own file and globaly scoped to my vue application

```
src
--components
--assets
----_variables.scss
```

and my Vue components are created in SFC(Single File Components) style like so

```
<template>
  <main>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <ProductsSection/>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import ProductsSection from "./ProductsSection.vue"
  export default {
    name: 'MainSection',
    components: {
      ProductsSection,
    },
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.content-wrapper{
  background-color: $bg-main;
}
</style>
```

**my question is what is the best implementation for this situation?**

Comment: "Proper" and "Best" in are subjective and tend to be based on opinion or other specific factors.

Comment: Of course .. But I just started learning VueJS a week ago .. And I am looking for some sort of best practices here .. I already implemented it .. But my implementation is very poor and redundant .. So I am looking for a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like to modifiy the html attribute:

```html
// index.html
<html lang="en" data-theme="dark">
...
</html>
```

```js
// App.vue
<template>
<button @click="changeTheme('light')">light theme</button>
<button @click="changeTheme('dark')">dark theme</button>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
  changeTheme(newTheme) {
     document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', newTheme)
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "./assets/style.scss";
</style>
```

```css
// style.scss
[data-theme="dark"] {
  --bg-color1: #121416;
  --font-color: #f4f4f4;
}
[data-theme="light"] {
  --bg-color1: #f4f4f4;
  --font-color: #121416;
}
...
body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color1);
  color: var(--font-color);
}
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: Sounds good .. But now I am using the normal CSS way of writing variables, not sass .. Your solution is what I am looking for, but I would prefer if I can use the sass style of writing variables

Comment: Can you translate it? I thought sass is like scss only without the parentheses.

Comment: i mean using sass variables like so : $color;
but in css i have to write var(--color)

Comment: you can do something like: `$bg-color: var(--bg-color)` and then use this sass variable instead of css custom property